# How to create email request forms and auto-responder?

Tags: php, email, forms, authentication, landing-page

I'm building a site in css and I'm pretty new to any code or script other than html and css.

I'm trying to create a landing page that requires an email from visitors and set up an auto responder to send to that newly submitted email. This would also be a signup for email newsletters.

I have some idea how to create the form and have looked into a bit. I don't know how to make it a requirement to get past the landing page and into the actual website or set up the auto-responder.

Any help would be much appreciated. Or if someone knows of a source that explains how to do this thing in particular it would be wonderful. I tried lynda.com but everything is so general and I can't seem to find info on exactly how to do this but I know its quite common. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would look into http://www.MailChimp.com which has a free email management account level and from there you can create your auto responders and also capture emails into a list.

To code this on your own when all your know is CSS and HTML would be a little too difficult.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am familiar with mail chimp and I believe you have to pay for the services which pretty much renders it useless for me. As a current college student I have absolutely no extra cash, lol. I don't even have enough cash to get by. lol. Do you know what i would need to learn to do something like this? I keep running into different ways to do the same thing which I'm aware is a reality but I just can't seem to find information on which I should use. At this point I'm starting with php. I'm going to learn how to do it regardless of difficulty.

Comment: Mailchimp has a free account. `If you have fewer than 2,000 subscribers, you can send up to 12,000 emails per month absolutely free. There's no expiring trial, contract, or credit card required. There are a few catches, though.` http://mailchimp.com/pricing/free/ I use this free account as do most of my clients it's well worth the free $0 price tag

Comment: WOW.. I'm crazy or that wasn't the case a few years ago. Lol. The other problem is that I am building this site for someone else and they are currently using some 3rd party client but would like to move away from it. I'm going to keep this in mind though! I got a couple of friends that will definitely want to start using it. Lol. Thanks.

Comment: Well check out MC's features see if it can replace whatever 3rd party app your using. It's certainly easier to user. If you feel this answered your questions feel free to hit the check mark.

Comment: No, I'm still looking for a way to learn how to do it myself...